# Вывод вакансий на сайте WordPress

Tags: wordpress, api

На странице сайта site.com/about/vakansii/ при переходе на любую вакансию, мы переходим на новую пустую страницу, а должна быть подгружена вакансия с вашего сайта. При этом, какое-то время в адресной строке появляется адрес вакансии (допустим site.com/about/vacancy/543664863/), но потом пропадает и остаётся только site.com/about/vacancy.

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Ни в ВП ни на "нашем" сайте нет вакансий. Исправляй вопрос, снабдив его подробностями.

Comment: Есть 2 страницы. На одной есть шорткод со всеми вакансиями, на другой шорткод с вакансией (не с конкретной, а для вставки). По идее, вакансии передаются через АПИ, но не выводятся. Что делать и где ковырять я не знаю. 
Есть еще плагин с НН вакансиями и там прописаны ID, но их количество больше, чем самих вакансий и у меня подозрение, что плагин не работает.

Comment: 1.. Исправляй вопрос. 2. В ВП нет шоркодов для вакансий. Никому не известно что у тебя и как. 3. См п1

Comment: Есть вот такая штука на странице в блоке с единичной вакансией - [vcs-vacancy] и [vcs-vacancies] на странице в блоке со всеми вакансиями.

Comment: Это ни о чем не говорит, кроме того что это два шорткода и один из них выводит все вакансии, а второй одну конкретную. Я понимаю что Вам все может казаться очевидным, но по-факту вся информация которая у нас есть, что есть два шорткода, вакансии тянутся по АПИ и не выводятся и что есть некий плагин от НН. Вы бы кому-то смогли помочь имея такой объем информации? Если думаете что причина в плагине, то логично обратиться к разработчикам плагина или написать на их форум поддержки.

Comment: К сожалению это всё, что я нашел в админке, . Человек, который работал с этим, не доступен. ТП НН пока молчит.